# Using gitignore, what is the proper way to ignore a directory with everything in it, i.e. with double asterisk or single or none?

Tags: gitignore, subdirectory

I want to find out the proper way to exclude a subdirectory with everything in it in `.gitignore` For this, I am trying to understand the different ways of excluding a specific directory in `.gitignore`. For this, I performed a test (below), but it is a bit confusing and unclear what the difference between different uses is.

Test files:

```bash
$ tree hey/
hey/
├── a
├── ab
└── abc
    └── a

2 directories, 2 files
```

- Method 1: Only the name, without slash and asterisk (`hey`)

```bash
$ tail -1 .gitignore
hey
$ git check-ignore -v hey hey/ hey/* hey/*/*
.gitignore:10:hey   hey
.gitignore:10:hey   hey/
.gitignore:10:hey   hey/a
.gitignore:10:hey   hey/ab
.gitignore:10:hey   hey/abc
.gitignore:10:hey   hey/abc/a
```

- Method 2: With slash, without asterisk (`hey/`)

```bash
$ tail -1 .gitignore
hey/
$ git check-ignore -v hey hey/ hey/* hey/*/*
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey/
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey/a
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey/ab
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey/abc
.gitignore:10:hey/  hey/abc/a
```

- Method 3: With slash and asterisk (`hey/*`)

```bash
$ tail -1 .gitignore
hey/*
$ git check-ignore -v hey hey/ hey/* hey/*/*
.gitignore:10:hey/* hey/
.gitignore:10:hey/* hey/a
.gitignore:10:hey/* hey/ab
.gitignore:10:hey/* hey/abc
.gitignore:10:hey/* hey/abc/a
```

- Method 4: With slash and asterisk (`hey/**`)

```bash
$ tail -1 .gitignore
hey/**
$ git check-ignore -v hey hey/ hey/* hey/*/*
.gitignore:10:hey/**    hey/
.gitignore:10:hey/**    hey/a
.gitignore:10:hey/**    hey/ab
.gitignore:10:hey/**    hey/abc
.gitignore:10:hey/**    hey/abc/a
```

The use of asterisks in `.gitignore` are defined as follows:

| Expression |  |
| --- | --- |
| `*` | matches zero or additional characters |
| `**` | matches any file or zero or additional directories |

The results of the test above suggest that:

| Expression |  |
| --- | --- |
| Method 1 `hey` | Excludes everything that is `hey` (`hey` file, `hey/` directory,`hey/*/*` etc) |
| Method 2 `hey/` | Same as `hey` |
| Method 3 `hey/*` | Does not exclude `hey` as a file, but excludes it if it is a directory |
| Method 4 `hey/**` | Same as `hey/*` for this specific case |

My questions are:

- In this use case, could there be any scenarios where there would be a difference between using `hey/*` and `hey/**`? Or would they work the same way?
- Why does `hey/` work the same way as `hey`?
- What is the best practice for excluding a specific subdirectory with everything in it?